# Intent from one two activities to one

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 activities Activity A,Activity B, and Activity C. I'm passing an intent from Activity A to Activity B with some values. And Activity B is receiving it without any problems. But the problem arises when I start Activity B from `onBackPress()` of Activity C . I have overridden the `onBackPress()` in Activity C and put the intent code in there. I only want to start activity B from Activity C and not pass any intent extra values. But when I press the back button, it gives me NPE because no value was received by the intent in Activity B. How to solve this?

Basically what I need is the intent in Activity B should receive values from Activity A and not from Activity C.

Activity A:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
            i.putExtra("artist_id", artistsModel.getArtistID());
            aContext.startActivity(i);


        }
```

Activity B:

```
 ArtistId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("artist_id");

 public void onClick(View view) {


                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityC.class);
                        intent1.putExtra("ArtistIDs", ArtistId );
                        startActivity(intent1);


                    }
```

Activity C:

```
 public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent i = new Intent(this , ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: put some random values from C to B with putExtra, then check it in B that values coming from A or C ,and take it only if it coming from A.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the `Intent` if the user come from C, then in `onCreate` of Activity change your logic to:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("artist_id")){
     ArtistId=intent.getExtras().getLong("artist_id");

   }else{

     ArtistId=0;
  }
```

What it does is it checks if the intent hasExtra with name `"artist_id"` if `true` it assigns it to `ArtistId` else `ArtistId` becomes zero.

Comment: Yeah I know, but It will destroy Activity C which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove code from Activity C:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

       // Intent code or don't 

    }
```

In this case your **Activity B** will be resumed if you have not finished **Activity B** else you have to code for **intent** to start **Activity B** from **Activity C**.

Comment: Yeah I know, but It will destroy Activity C which I don't want. I'm using back button to go to Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a null check on the `getExtras()` for `ArtistId`.
You are getting a `NullPointerException` because `getExtras()` is `null` and you are trying to retrieve long data from it.

So solution is

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
     ArtistId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("artist_id", 0);
}
```

Also I'm putting `getLong("artist_id, 0)` to get default value as `0` if we don't find this key in the extras

Answer (score 0):

ok Activity-A  code is ok but in Activity-C onBackPressed() instead of using this code

```
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent i = new Intent(this , ActivityB.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```

use this

```
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent i = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
}
```

and in Activity-B class in onClick

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityC.class);
                        intent1.putExtra("ArtistIDs", ArtistId );
                        startActivityforResult(intent1, 1);
```

and override @Override onActivityResult method

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
       //  doAnything after back from activity-c or do't do anything
}
    }
```

i hope this help and solve your problem